# Enhancing ggvis axes

Tags: r, ggvis

I am looking for the best way to enhance a chart

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

df <- data.frame(Year=c(1954:2013), Count=rep(as.integer(c(1,3,4,2)),15))

df %>%
ggvis(~Year,~Count)
```

[image]

I would like to show only whole numbers in the y-axis and remove the thousand-comma in the x-axis

I have coerced both fields to factors with this hack

```
df %>%
 ggvis(~as.factor(Year),~as.factor(Count)) %>% 
 layer_points() %>%
 add_axis("y", title="Count") %>%
 add_axis("x", title="Year") %>%
 scale_ordinal("y", reverse=TRUE)
```

but now I am showing every year, rather than the more appropriate 5 year values shown before
and amending the label properties only helps so much

Help much appreciated

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This can be done using the `format=` in the `add_axis` along with `subdivide` argument -

A `subdivide = 0` means no minor ticks between major ticks (defined in `values`).  The `format='####'` makes everything whole numbers.

```
 df %>%
  ggvis(~Year,~Count) %>%
  layer_points() %>%
  add_axis("x", title="Year",  format="####") %>%
  add_axis("y", subdivide = 0, values = seq(1, 4, by = 1), format='####')
```

which gives:

[image]